# Juju lxc deploy not working!

Tags: server, juju, maas, openstack, lxc

I have a problem deploying services on lxc containers.I have set up maas and juju and have 4 servers deployed. Here is a juju status:

```
environment: maas
machines:
"0":
agent-state: started
agent-version: 1.24.0
dns-name: node4.maas
instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-98e78102-1e47-11e5-885d-0030487c90c8/
series: trusty
containers:
  0/lxc/9:
    agent-state-info: 'container failed to start and was destroyed: juju-machine-0-lxc-9'
    instance-id: pending
    series: trusty
hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=2 mem=16384M
state-server-member-status: has-vote
```

I can deploy services on single machine but can't deploy it to lxc.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The best way of debugging this is to take a look at the debug-log to see if it gives away anymore information

```
juju debug-log -n 1000
```

There have been a number of improvements in this area over the last few months. Trying again with a more up to date version of juju might help